# System.Windows.Forms FileNotFoundException occured although it's referenced

Tags: c#, .net, dll, .net-assembly, filenotfoundexception

I am getting a `System.IO.FileNotFoundException`, which states that `System.Windows.Forms.dll` is not found, although I referenced the assembly (and of course  removed and re-referenced it).
I have to load external `*.resx` files and write them into a sqlite-db.
Here's the code part which throws the exception:

```
private void LoadResources()
{
    string[] resources = Directory.GetFiles(Settings.Default.DefaultFilePath, "*.resx", SearchOption.AllDirectories);
    foreach (var resource in resources)
    {
        var resReader = new ResXResourceReader(resource);
        var dict = resReader.GetEnumerator(); // Exception raised at 29th iteration
        while (dict.MoveNext())
        {
            if (dict.Key.GetType() != typeof (string))
                continue;

            // unrelevant stuff...
```

However, the exception is always raised at the same iteration (29th) regarding the `foreach`-loop (so, not directly), not depending on the underlying file.

---

**Edit**:

*StackTrace*:

```
System.IO.FileNotFoundException occurred
  FileName=System.Windows.Forms
  FusionLog==== Zustandsinformationen vor Bindung ===
LOG: DisplayName = System.Windows.Forms
 (Partial)
WRN: Für eine Assembly wurden partielle Bindungsinformationen bereitgestellt:
WRN: Assemblyname: System.Windows.Forms | Domänen-ID: 1
WRN: Eine partielle Bindung tritt auf, wenn nur ein Teil des Assemblyanzeigenamens bereitgestellt wird.
WRN: Dies führt möglicherweise dazu, dass die Sammelmappe eine falsche Assembly lädt.
WRN: Geben Sie die Textidentität der Assembly mit allen Einzelheiten an. 
WRN: Dazu gehören der einfache Name, die Version und Kultur und das öffentliche Schlüsseltoken.
WRN: Weitere Informationen und allgemeine Lösungen für dieses Problem finden Sie im Whitepaper unter "http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=109270".
LOG: Appbase = file:///C:/Users/patrick/Documents/Visual Studio 2015/Projects/GitTranslationTool/CleanTranslationTool/CleanTranslationTool/bin/Debug/
LOG: Ursprünglicher PrivatePath = NULL
Aufruf von Assembly : System.Windows.Forms, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089.
  HResult=-2147024894
  Message=Die Datei oder Assembly "System.Windows.Forms" oder eine Abhängigkeit davon wurde nicht gefunden. Das System kann die angegebene Datei nicht finden.
  Source=mscorlib
  StackTrace:
       bei System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly._nLoad(AssemblyName fileName, String codeBase, Evidence assemblySecurity, RuntimeAssembly locationHint, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean suppressSecurityChecks)
       bei System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.nLoad(AssemblyName fileName, String codeBase, Evidence assemblySecurity, RuntimeAssembly locationHint, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean suppressSecurityChecks)
  InnerException:
```

Regarding an example:

```
private void LoadResources()
{
    string[] resources = Directory.GetFiles(@"your\folder\with\resources", "*.resx", SearchOption.AllDirectories);
    var counter = 0;
    foreach (var resource in resources)
    {
        counter++;
        var resReader = new ResXResourceReader(resource);
        var dict = resReader.GetEnumerator();
        while (dict.MoveNext())
        {
            if (dict.Key.GetType() != typeof (string))
                continue;
            Debug.WriteLine("{0}: {1}", dict.Key, dict.Value);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please show the *exact* exception, including stack trace, and ideally a [mcve].

Comment: FileNotFoundException is thrown even when you haven't referred an assembly required by the assembly that you do have referred. From what I understand from your question, In 29th iteration your assembly1(System.Windows.Forms) requires another assembly2 to complete its work. You should find out what assembly2 is? Add reference to it. That should fix your problem.

Comment: Why I have the feeling that your _unrelevant stuff_ is instead relevant here? Please, just for an experiment, try to comment out the _unrelevant stuff_ and verify if the error persist.

Comment: @JonSkeet thanks for referencing that ressource, will be helpful in future, updated my answer.
Steve Im currently just printing the key-value pairs.

Comment: This happens on the 29th file or on the 29th entry of the first file? Difficult to tell what could be the cause of the error without having the data processed. I suggest to look at the file data trying to isolate the line that causes the error.

Comment: It looks like there's an InnerException, but you've cut that off the stack trace. That's likely to be rather important...

Comment: @Steve thx for help. It happens on the 29th file, (foreach-loop), **independent from the file** *(I removed the original 29th file, didnt change anything)*

Comment: @JonSkeet nope, InnerException is `null`